# how to map an api into a paragraph

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am trying to map an array of an api to display paragraphs for every index within the array. However I keep getting an error :

**> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating

> 'post.game_indices.version.name')**

But when I console log post and use my buttons below it displays what I want and not undefined. So why is it undefined when I want to map the paragraphs?

'''

import React, {useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import instance from './axios'

const Home = () => {

```
const [post, setPost] = useState(null);
const [error,setError] = useState(null);
const [showTypes,setShowTypes]=useState(false);
const [showAbilities,setShowAbilities]=useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    instance.get("bulbasaur/").then((response) => {
        setPost(response.data);
        }).catch(error => {
            setError(error);
        })
},[]);
console.log(post);
if (error) return `Error: ${error.message}`;
if (!post) return 'no post!'



return (
<>
<h1>{post.name}</h1>
<button onClick={()=>setShowTypes(!showTypes)}>types</button>
{showTypes? <p>{(post.types[0].type.name)}</p>:null}
{showTypes? <p>{(post.types[1].type.name)}</p>:null}
<button onClick={()=>setShowAbilities(!showAbilities)}>abilities</button>
{showAbilities? <p>{(post.abilities[0].ability.name)}</p>:null}
{showAbilities? <p>{(post.abilities[1].ability.name)}</p>:null}
{/* <button onClick={gameVersion}>game versions</button> */}
{post.game_indices.version.name.map(name => <p key={post.game_indices.version.name}>{name}</p>)}
</>
)
```

}

export default Home;

'''

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to get a better understanding about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Another good read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions?. Afterwards, please edit your question to add all the relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I recreated your app and found a problem - you should map on array `post.game_indices` and then display `index.version.name`

```
{post.game_indices.map((index, idx) => <p key={idx}>{index.version.name}</p>)}
```

Comment: yep, so there was no version directly on game_indices. It was an array

Comment: oh, it's a famous API for all newbies in React - been using it during my courses frequently:  https://pokeapi.co/

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the fact that you `version` is not an object in `game_indices` (it is `undefined`, which means maybe `game_indices` is an empty object or it does not contain the `version` key). Can you please check your `post` object again ?

Comment: `game_indices` is an array of objects, so needs to be mapped (https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/bulbasaur)